# Image Based Flair (Downloadable Implementation [v2.1])

Tags: discussion, flair, images

## Image Based Flair

I have created an implementation of flair which generates an image of your current reputation automatically. It is currently using PHP GD.

> [Download Source (Version 2.1 - 2009-08-03)](http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/flair/flair.zip)

---

### Current Features

**Configurable**
Edit your accounts by opening `system/config.yaml` and editing the values.

**Customizable**
Create your own themes by editing/adding YAML files. (2 themes by default [basic,advanced] in 2 different flavors [normal, inverted])

**Expandable**
Currently supports all 4 SO sites. Adapts to new additions to the StackOverflow family with a simple config file.

---

### Examples

**This script no longer works due to the new flair API. I have no intention of updating it.**

<sub>The desktop theme included in the distribution will not render exactly the same as the above. The reason is that I didn't include one font used due to licensing restrictions. For reference, the reputation font (missing) is **DIN 1451 Engschrift LT**. The theme files are as in, so by dropping in the font as `dinb.ttf` in the `system/fonts` folder, it should render as the above.</sub>

---

### Changelog

**Version 2.1 - 2009-08-03:**

- Fixed `imageantialias()` error on packaged versions of `php-gd`.
- Renamed and reorganized themes.
- Added light-bg version of the SO logos.

**Version 2.0 - 2009-07-31:**

- Complete rewrite. The theme engine is now extremely flexible and allows the creation of complex themes. I've added one as an example.

**Version 1.2 - 2009-07-25:**

- Added "service" mode. To use, make sure `id` is set to `false` in `system/config.yaml`, then specify the ID before the theme: `/1/basic/StackOverflow.png`.

**Version 1.1 - 2009-07-25:**

- Fixed `display` parameter being ignored for some objects
- Fixed bug where a `badges.icons.size` value 0 or lower made the generation fail.

---

### Installation

You need **PHP 5.2.3** or greater, **php_gd**, and `allow_fopen_url = 1` for this script to work. Make sure to make `system/cache` writable (an `.htaccess` file protects the directory from outside reads).

---

### Combining Images

**Kyle Cronin** asked if I could provide an example on how to combine the images. You can use the following script to do so:

```
<?php
// If you have PHP 5.3 and the timezone isn't set properly.
date_default_timezone_set (@date_default_timezone_get());

require_once ('system/classes/spyc.php');
require_once ('system/classes/Image.php');

$theme = 'advanced';

header ('Expires: ' . date('r', time() + 300));
$flair_config = Spyc::YAMLLoad('system/config.yaml');
$domain = 'http://mydomain.com/flair/';

$width = 0;
$height = 0;
$padding = 10;

$images = array();

foreach($flair_config as $site => $data) {
    $images[$site] = new Image();
    $images[$site]->open($domain . $theme . '/' . $site . '.png');
    $width += $padding + $images[$site]->width();
    $height = max($height, $images[$site]->height());
}

$width -= $padding;

$img = new Image();
$img->new_transparent($width, $height);

$img->set_fill_color('#000');
$img->fill();

$offset = 0;

foreach($images as $image) {
    $img->paste($image, $offset, 0);
    $offset += $image->width() + $padding;
}

$img->output(IMG_PNG);
?>
```

Comment: not that I object, by why is this 'downloadable'? why not offer a simple service that offers this by including the site/userid in the url?

Comment: **@Kyle Cronin:** I don't have the bandwidth and the CPU usage to constantly generate images for everyone.

Comment: @Andrea I can help with the bandwidth, CPU and domains, you interested? : - )

Comment: **@chakrit:** Sure, go ahead if you want to... The source code will need small modifications in order to work as a service. I'll leave that to your capable hands. Just be sure to properly attribute credit.

Comment: Related question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475/can-we-get-flair-as-an-image

Comment: @Andrew problems was ... I sucked at PHP : - ( ... but I'll give it some time tonight anyway : - )

Comment: **@chakrit:** Alright, I did modifications. Download the latest version.

Comment: any chance for an update to this? looks like stack exchange changed and now breaks this image flair.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Got any plans to publish this as WordPress plugin

Comment: It really doesn't need to... Just edit your templates to add the image in the sidebar.

Comment: @Benny: The whole thing needs to be rewritten for the new API. I don't have time to do it. I also won't be creating a WP plugin for this.

Comment: @Benny: It's not a question of help, it's a question of lack of time.